# Reference View in another Java file

Tags: android, cordova

I'm creating a plugin for Phonegap which needs to reference the WebView created in the DroidGap.java file.

Would it be possible to reference a view held in another java file using the findByViewId method?

Comment: What do you mean 'reference a view held by another java file'? Get a view that an object has? Or inflate a view from xml that the base project has?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA: I mean, the view is created in another java file, and i just want to point to it.

Comment: Then just have that java file have a getter for the view that you need. This is not preferred, however. A better way of doing that would be to have the getter take a context parameter and inflate a new view that is exactly like the view you desire.